# Neo4j if a node has no outgoing edges delete that node otherwise return its next nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to use Neo4j Cypher to implement the following function: given a node, check if it has any outgoing edges with a specific relationship type. If so, return the nodes it can reach out by those edges, otherwise delete this node. And my code is like this

```
MATCH (m:Node{Properties})
WITH (size((m)-[:type]->(:Node))) AS c,m 
WHERE c=0
DETACH DELETE m
```

However I don't know how to apply the if/else condition here, and this code only implements part of what I need. I'd really appreciate your help and suggestions!

For example the database is like this:

A-[type]->B

A-[type]->C

If the original node is A and it has two edges with that type to B and C, then I want the query to return B and C as result.
If the original node is B, it should be deleted because there's no such outgoing edge from B.

Comment: You will probably want to use APOC conditional procedures

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I have some issues using APOC query in java..it always got some erros

Comment: well, we can always help you with that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UPDATED]

The following query uses a `FOREACH` hack to conditionally delete `m`, and returns either the found `n` nodes, or `NULL` if there were none.

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (m:Node {...Properties...})-[:type]->(n:Node)
FOREACH(x IN CASE WHEN n IS NULL THEN [1] END | DETACH DELETE m)
RETURN n
```

You could also use the APOC procedure [apoc.do.when](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/cypher-execution/conditionals/) instead of the `FOREACH` hack:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (m:Node {...Properties...})-[:type]->(n:Node)
CALL apoc.do.when(n IS NULL, 'DETACH DELETE m', '', {m: m}) YIELD value
RETURN n
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But it seems like it can not return all accessible nodes when the original node has outgoing edges with that type.

Comment: Your original question did not request that anything be returned. See my updated answer

Comment: Thank you so much and sorry I didn't not describe my question clearly! :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, I'm a little confused about the "x" in FOREACH clause, does that mean the case number?

Comment: The `x` and the `[1]` are just necessary to get the `FOREACH` clause to be legal and to work as intended (execute `DETACH DELETE m` iff `n IS NULL`). The `1` value in `[1]` could have been anything at all, and the `x` value is ignored. The APOC approach is a bit more understandable for the uninitiated, but *might* be less performant.

Comment: Oooh I see, thank you again for your clear explanation!